# Setting a CMake with Clion

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

[image]

How do I solve these errors when trying to build using CLion in the MinGW environment.

Comment: Please check how to ask effctive question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It looks pretty clearly like you need to install `make` and a `C` compiler and a `C++` compiler.

Comment: Did you solved it?? Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a case of making sure the correct tools are on the PATH, but rather you are missing GNU make and the C/C++ compilers. You have probably installed a minGW package that is too minimal for your needs. The following quote is from the [current installation guide](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/getting_started) . .  .

> Unlike the case with mingw-get-inst.exe, you are no longer obliged to
>   install any particular set of packages. If you do wish to install
>   mingw-get-inst.exe's obligatory set, (including the GNU C Compiler,
>   the GNU Debugger (GDB), and the GNU make tool), you should select the
>   mingw-base package for installation.